# Which is the best practice to include a .ZIP file inside an Android .APK?

Tags: android, zip, apk, assets

I need to provide a zip file (~4-5MB) as a bundle for my app, so I want to include it in my Android project.

The only way I found to achieve this is to put it inside the raw folder or alternatively inside the assets folder, that seems to be the preferable choice, but... this folder is limited up to 1 MB for compressed files.

So... I'd like to know which is the best way to do that. I have to use the raw folder instead the asset one, and why? Or you can suggest me another way to put this file inside the asset folder?

Answer (score 0):

actually, there is a workaround that works nicely with the 1MB-limitation. Give your bundle a mp3 extension and load it from assets. Then unzip it from your application. Note that this is a workaround and not an official solution.

Best way would be to split the file and put the pieces together when you load it.